# How do I write an async unit test method in F#

Tags: unit-testing, f#, async-await

**How do I write an async test method in F#?**

I'm referencing the following [code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn818493.aspx):

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task CorrectlyFailingTest()
{
  await SystemUnderTest.FailAsync();
}
```

**This is my failed attempt:**

```
[<Test>]
let ``Correctly failing test``() = async {

        SystemUnderTest.FailAsync() | Async.RunSynchronously
    }
```

Comment: Is this using NUnit?

Comment: Yes. I'm using NUnit.

Comment: Have you tried simply removing the `async { }` and making the test synchronous? I.e., `SystemUnderTest.FailAsync() |> Async.AwaitIAsyncResult |> Async.RunSynchronously`, and that's it. Or if a synchronous test would not fit your requirements, and the test *has* to be asynchronous, then I'd recommend looking into [Expecto](https://github.com/haf/expecto), where asynchronous tests are the norm rather than the exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So after a bit of research, it turns out that this is more difficult than it ought to be. https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/34

That being said a workaround was mentioned. This seems kinda lame but, it looks like declaring a task delegate outside as a member and leveraging it is a viable work around.

The examples mentioned in the thread:

```
open System.Threading.Tasks
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices

let toTask computation : Task = Async.StartAsTask computation :> _

[<Test>]
[<AsyncStateMachine(typeof<Task>)>]
member x.``Test``() = toTask <| async {
    do! asyncStuff()
}
```

And

```
open System.Threading.Tasks
open NUnit.Framework

let toAsyncTestDelegate computation = 
    new AsyncTestDelegate(fun () -> Async.StartAsTask computation :> Task)

[<Test>]
member x.``TestWithNUnit``() = 
    Assert.ThrowsAsync<InvalidOperationException>(asyncStuff 123 |> toAsyncTestDelegate)
    |> ignore

[<Test>]
member x.``TestWithFsUnit``() = 
    asyncStuff 123 
    |> toAsyncTestDelegate
    |> should throw typeof<InvalidOperationException>
```

XUnit had a similar problem and did come up with a solution:
https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/955

So you should be able to do this in xunit

```
[<Fact>]
let ``my async test``() =
  async {
    let! x = someAsyncCall()
    AssertOnX
  }
```

Sorry if this is not the most satisfying answer.

Comment: I tried the XUnit example you provided and got the following error:

Comment: Error FS0001 This expression was expected to have type
    'Async<'a>'    
but here has type
    'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult>'

Comment: I applied your XUnit example with: do! Async.AwaitTask( someAsyncCall())|> Async.Ignore

Comment: Checking out: http://hackerferret.com/uncategorized/breakdown-my-ah-ha-moment-with-f-and-functional-programming/

Answer (score 4):

```
open Xunit

[<Fact>]
let ``my async test``() =
  async {
    do! Async.AwaitTask(someAsyncCall())|> Async.Ignore
    AssertOnX
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I asked https://github.com/fsprojects/FsUnit/issues/153 because I think that it is a responsibility of the F# unit testing framework to provide a right binding.
Meanwhile, this looks the best for me.

```
    open System.Threading.Tasks

    let runAsyncTest async = async |> Async.StartImmediateAsTask :> Task

    [<Test>]
    let ``Some test`` () = runAsyncTest <| async {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but now can use the `task` builder from the [Ply](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ply/) package for testing C# async methods in Xunit like so:

```ml
    open FSharp.Control.Tasks
    open System.Threading
    open Xunit
    
    let ``Test some Task returning async method`` () =
        task {
            let! actual = MyType.GetSomethingAsync()
            Assert.Equal(expected, actual)
            
            return ()
        }
```